# Accessing The Laravel SQL Relationship without Local Key

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am new in Laravel. I have two models: `User` and `Car`. I wish to access the car data from the user entity in the controller, but I could not find how to do it. In addition, the database is fixed with the columns and the administrator refuses to do any change on it.

Here is the `User` model:

```php
class User extends Model {
  protected $primaryKey = 'idUser';
  protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'age', 'address', 'gender', 'phone', 'email'
  ];
}
```

And then this is my `Car` model:

```php
class Car extends Model {
  protected $primaryKey = 'idCar';
  protected $fillable = [
    'carNumber', 'carMachineNumber', 'type', 'model', 'year', 'idUser'
  ];

  public user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'idUser');
  }
}
```

In the controller and the blade templates, I wish I can access the car data from the user entity. For example when I want to get the car type data then I would access it by:

```php
$user->car->type
```

It would be even better if I will be able to access all of the cars a user has by this line of code:

```php
$user->car->all();
```

How to make it possible? What should I add to the controllers without making any change to database? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have standard primary key `id`, so you will have to specify all the keys in the relationship (`idCar`).

Car model

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'idUser', 'idCar');
}
```

But this will get you `$car->user` which is the owner of the car.
With the way you designed your database, a user can have many cars.

User model

```
public function cars() {
    return $this->hasMany(Car::class, 'idUser', 'idUser');
}
```

When you want to retrieve the cars belong to a user, you can

```
$user->cars;
```

or

```
foreach($user->cars as $car) {
    // $car
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain why u put the `idUser` as the foreign key for `idCar`? Doesn't that relationship mean that **The car 1 belongs to user 1, The car 2 belongs to user 2**, and so on? Is that accomodate the case **The car 1 and car 2 belong to user 1**?

Comment: In Car model, there is a field idUser which is a foreign key to User model. idCar is not a foreign key but a primary key.

Comment: right, a car can belong to one user, but a user can have many cars.

Comment: With those, can I access car data from user without need to join table/use where statement and just by using the eloquent relationship like `$user->car->all()`?

Comment: yes, just $user->cars should get you all car objects.

Comment: @Dhana D. you are attempting $user->car->all() but all() only works on model and does not work on eloquent relation. So, add a relation cars() in your user model and access all cars the user have like $user->cars() just like Anurat suggested.